# Loop file from the end?

Tags: php, file, foreach

I have a text file like this

> 2018-10-09    1
>
> 2018-11-12    1
>
> 2018-11-13    7
>
> 2018-11-15    1
>
> 2018-11-18    7

I loop the file to display the result like this

```
<?php
    $offers = file('logs/offer.txt');
    foreach($offers as $line) {
        $lineArray = explode("\t", $line);
        list($date, $quantity) = $lineArray;
        echo '<tr>      
        <td>' . $date . '</td>
        <td>' .$quantity. '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

I get the result but I want to start from the end of the file and echo the result like this (start with latest date)

> 2018-11-18    7
>
> 2018-11-15    1
>
> 2018-11-13    7
>
> 2018-11-12    1
>
> 2018-10-09    1

Comment: I suppose you thought of doing a FOR loop from count($offers)-1 and decrementing the counter instead of incrementing it?

Comment: Of course if the file may become very large the DUP is probably the best solution

Comment: You could also say that the data should be in a database, there are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reverse the file contents array using [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) before using foreach...

```
$offers = file('logs/offer.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$offers = array_reverse($offers);
foreach($offers as $line) {
```

Note I've also added `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` which will take the new line off the end of each row, you can remove it if required.

Comment: I suppose that `array_reverse(array_reverse);` should be `array_reverse($offers)`?